# Annotations and Bounding Box Definition in Object Detection

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, object-detection

I'm having confusion about the concepts of object detection.

If the dataset has been annotated to have ground truth in (x, y) of the four vertices, then why are the papers (using the same dataset) are using a bounding box that is defined by (x,y,w,h) - box center, width, and height?

I'm sure I miss something here, can someone help?

Comment: What's the problem of specifying box coordinates via either corner positions or center+height+width?

Comment: I'm confused why use the BBox as center+height+width when the annotations of the dataset are in corner positions? Should we specify the bbox coordinates the same with  the dataset annotations?

Comment: They can be translated to each other. So, I see no harm using any of them. The specific papers may have chosen a particular representation based on readability, if they haven't specified anything.To be honest, I find center representation easier to read.

Comment: I see. When the dataset annotations are in corner positions and the paper shows bbox coordinates as center+height+width, does that mean that in the code they have converted from corner positions to center+height+width?

Comment: it’s quite possible